# openquery conversion failed because the data value overflowed the data type used by the provider

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 to fetched data from another server using linked server.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (METER, 
       'SELECT 
             ME.Col1
            ,ME."ext"               AS ext         
            ,ME."t-date"                AS Date
            ,ME."per-id"                    AS Person
            ,PE."con-id"                AS Contact
            ,PE."add-id"                AS Address
            ,SC."contact-title"         AS Member
            ,SC."given"             AS Giver
            ,SC."surname"               AS lastname 

        FROM PU."member" ME
            LEFT JOIN PU."personal" PE
              ON ME."per-id" = PE."per-id"
            LEFT JOIN PU."cont" SC
              ON PE."contactid" = SC."contactid"

        WHERE ME."t-date" IS NULL 
           OR ME."t-date" >= NOW()')
```

I'm getting error:

```
 OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "METER" returned message    "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status   value, if available. No work was done.".
  Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
  Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].T_DATE" from OLE DB   provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "METER". Conversion failed because the data   value overflowed the data type used by the provider.
```

If I remove where condition and executing this, I'm getting same error as well. So I think "Date" is not causing any issue here. Please Correct me if I'm wrong.

However, if I remove **,SC."contact-title" AS Member** from the above query, it gives me result and works fine.

I got information that:

Length of the data in each field must be less than the length described in the schema. For contact-title defined as certain character and data need to be less than that. - I understand this.

My question is in select query I'm trying to fetch the data and I'm not inserting any where. But, still why this character length mismatch ? As per my understanding if I'm inserting it somewhere then there could be a issue. But just select should not give issue.

I'm just fetching data from 3rd party server and displaying. Is there any issue could be at my end/my database? If yes, how?

Could anyone has faced similar issue and how to solve this?

Comment: can you try `,SC."contact-title"` with out the **AS Member**?

Comment: What is the Linked server pointing to? another SQL server or an Oracle Server? Try converting the T-DATE to DateTime in the OPENQUERY itself if it's MSSQL and if it's Oracle the length of the milliseconds field might be too long.

Comment: @Sam , could you please tell me in details, how you would like me to convert this? Any example by looking at query would help?

Comment: **CAST(ME."t-date" AS DATETIME) AS Date**  But this would work only if the linked server METER is a MSSQL Server. Can you tell me what the linked server is pointing to? Is it an Access DB or a MSSQL DB or an Oracle DB?

Comment: Its proactive / Oracle. I think, issue is not with date. Its with "SC."contact-title" AS Member" . Somehow ODBC driver is not allowing the length greater than schema specified length. So I need to TRIM data value to make less than schema specified length (that is 15). Any idea to receive data that is less than 15? I mean, the data may be more than 15, however, I will only read less than 15.

Comment: In the WHERE condition try LENGTH( "SC."contact-title") < 15

Comment: Its the same error. I think, somehow query from SQL server is not recognized by Proactive. Any other clue?

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: What *is* the type of `PU.cont.contact-title`?

Answer (score 0):

Just changed  SC."contact-title"  to substring(SC."contact-title",1,14) and it worked. Note- both SUBSTR and SUBSTRING is working fine.